# How to send data from a browser to a server?

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, browser

I want to send a file to the server, can I do that using only PHP? Or should I use javascript?

And is there a library to help me? I don't want (and also don't know how) to convert files into char* and send using sockets.

Comment: What's wrong with `<input type="file" />`?  Have you tried it?

Comment: What you're looking for is a combination of the `<input type="file">` tag, and the relevant PHP code to handle an uploaded file. There are many tutorials available online on this subject; try searching "php handle file upload" and you're likely to get something helpful.

Comment: Try [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) first, that should get you going.

Comment: No, but can i send file without creating socket? i write mail server-client application, the server application should receive files with sockets.

Comment: @PleaseHelpMe The whole internet works on socket connections... otherwise you're not sending data.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, inattentively read. 
If `<input type="file" />` does not fit, try to use html5 FileReader object.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: He's uploading a file.  That's certainly not easiest with AJAX.

Comment: True, that doesn't answer the question content. It does answer the question header, though - if the user is only submitting some small data, they certainly wouldn't need to convert it to a file and upload it. Since the asker seems unclear on the options, it's probably worth mentioning.